# Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> La Granda Sigelo montras Liberecon personigita kiel sidanta Junono portanta kronon kun sep radioj.

Shouldn't *personigita* be in the accusative case since it refers to *Liberecon*?

Comment: I found your example in the Wikipedia article [Granda Sigelo de Francio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granda_Sigelo_de_Francio). While I agree with Eduardo Trápani about the grammar, I would like to point out that the sentence is heavy with multiple participles. Rewriting it using subclauses instead for some of them, would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't "personigita" be in the accusative case since it refers to "Liberecon"?

Ambaŭ frazoj eblas, sed ili signifas malsamajn aferojn.

```
Tio montras Liberecon personigita
```

signifas ke tio montras Liberecon tiel, ke ĝi estas personigita

```
Tio montras Liberecon personigitan
```

signifas ke tio montras tiun specifan Liberecon, la personigitan (oni suspektas la ekziston de aliaj Liberecoj)

Klarigon vi trovas en [Perverba priskribo de objekto](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/objekto.html), kun ekzemplo pli simpla:

```
Vi farbas la domon ruĝan.
(signifo: Vi farbas la ruĝan domon, ne alian)
```

kaj

```
Vi farbas la domon ruĝa.
(signifo: Vi farbas la domon tiel, ke ĝi fariĝas ruĝa)
```